# First direction proof for $\forall a,b\in\Bbb F(\|au+bv\|=\|bu+av\|)\iff\|u\|=\|v\|)$

Tags: linear-algebra

[Confirmation required on proof of $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{F} (\|au+bv\| = \|bu+av\|) \Leftrightarrow \|u\| = \|v\|)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706419/confirmation-required-on-proof-of-forall-a-b-in-mathbbf-aubv-buav)

In this post the OP proved the forward direction as such:

Proof. (⇒). Assume that $‖+‖=‖+‖$ for all $,∈ℝ$ then in particular for $=1$ and $=0$ we have $‖‖=‖‖$.

I was wondering how is this correct? To prove the forward direction we need to prove for all $a,b \in \Bbb R$  $‖+‖=‖+‖$ implies $‖‖=‖‖$, right? Is it allowed to set particular values to $a$ and $b$ like he did in this post?

Comment: Mind the brackets: ($\forall a,b: \ \|\dots \|=\|\dots\|$) $\Rightarrow$ $\|u\|=\|v\|$. The title od the post is misleading, the question post itself has it correctly.